# CComSafeArray change no of elements

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have created CComSafeArray object having 32 elements using the following statements. But after some operations I came to know that I need only 3 elements in the safe array. Is it possible to change the number of elements in the safe array after creating it?

```
CComSafeArray<VARIANT> x(32);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance looking for the `CComSafeArray::Resize()` member function?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9758bsfw(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Suppose the initial safe array has 32 elements. I filled first 3 elements with data. If I resize it to 3, will it cause any data loss of the first 3 elements? Will there be any performance overhead?

Comment: @Maanu: You won't lose the elements. I don't think there will be any significant performance overhead